# VERY long renders. 3 mins a frame?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Im' using OSX 10.11 el capitan. I've followed tutorials such as this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT0st6zLwI to make renders ore efficient. I don't have a GPU yet.
I'm using cycles render...
On some videos people are saying "it took only and 1 minute or so to render a whole clip. Why would my set up render so terribly slowly. lasting 3 mins just a render a single frame!!

Many thanks,

Joel

Comment: It depends mostly on what your scene contains really. If it's volumetrics/caustics heavy it's gonna take awhile and the only thing to remedy that is to use a GPU. Otherwise, you could try lowering you sample count and enabling denoising, or lower the image size. Unfortunately you can't really 'speed up' your rending times without doing at least some of the things listed in the tutorial.

Comment: Render can take a few seconds, a few minutes, hours, days... it all depends on the complexity of the scene, number of vertices, complexity of the materials, size of the images used, particles, physics, motion blur, the size in pixels of the image rendered, number of samples, and layers, etc, etc. Add to that the capacity of the hardware, number of cores, available RAM, kind of GPU, on other processes running simultaneously.... the list is long. 3 minutes is fast..., or  normal...  you can optimize.... or lower your expectations... or get a faster machine... or use a render farm...